# How to use Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition offline?

Tags: wpf, windows, uwp, speech-recognition, offline

I am trying to dictate speech to text offline which can be done by [Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.speechrecognition?view=winrt-20348) documentation doesn't provide the details on how to do continuous dictation **On Device** or **Offline**.

I am investigating the sample that Microsoft provides but not finding that option anywhere. [SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis)

Comment: Have you checked this document-[Define custom recognition constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/define-custom-recognition-constraints#specify-an-srgs-grammar-constraint-speechrecognitiongrammarfileconstraint). This document shows how to specify an SRGS grammar constraint in your app.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT, thanks but i want to use it for continuous dictation not specific words. It's strange that the older version System.Speech.Recogntion has this feature (low quality) but the new one Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition doesn't have such as basic feature.

Comment: Well, I have to say that continuous dictation requires a scenario with network. You can't use it without network. It will give you an error `Network Failure`.

Comment: I started continuous dictation async and my console app just sits there, doesn't recognize anything but also no error if I turn off wifi.